# Contruct the Deterministic Finite Automata

Tags: finite-automata

Give a DFA for $\Sigma = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ that recognizes strings over the alphabet $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ which are integers with a digit sum of $6$ and may have leading zeros. For example, $1230$ should be
in the language since $1 + 2 + 0 + 3 = 6$, and $0024$ or $24$ should be in the language since $0 + 0 + 2 + 4 = 6$, but $203$, $301$ and $2341$ should not be in the language since their digit sums are $5$,
$4$ and $10$ respectively.

Comment: Do you have any ideas for constructing this: what could be the states, for example?

Comment: possible this needs to be migrated to a CompSci SE. Not sure if there is a theoretical CS one though...

Comment: Take states from 0 to 7 such that if the  automaton is in state $i$ and the digit $j$ is entered, it goes to state $i+j$ or 7 whatever is smaller. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SZN $\texttt{cstheory.stackexchange.com}$